# Javascript GET request with headers - print result

Tags: javascript, python

Very new to JS and am trying to make a GET request to an API with a header. The below code appears to work (no errors) but I don't understand how to get it to print the data it has collected from the API.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'URL');
    xmlHttp.headers({'Authorization': 'Token REDACTED'}); 
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Basically am trying to do what this python code does:

```
header =  {'Authorization': 'Token REDACTED'}

response = requests.get("URL", headers = header)
print response.content
```

Comment: post the code where you attempted to call `http()`

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous call....

Comment: Ok, so is there anyway to do what I did in python in JS? Or no? @epascarello

Comment: Did you read the info in the dupe?

Comment: I did, but it's a little over my head. I'll try again. Thank you for your help!